# validate checkout fields on click of custom place order button with JS before submitting

Tags: javascript, wordpress, payment-gateway, checkout

I've integrated a **custom payment gateway** into woocommerce during checkout. 
The payment is processed on click of the custom place order button, I need to check for **validation of checkout form** on click of place order **with JS**  before submission of place order. As I want to process the **payment with js** on click of place order after validation.

Does any one knows? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by plain Javascript then you have to form logic according to your need and if you prefer using Jquery then use jquery validate plugin which is very easy to use. 
Refere here [Jquery Validator](https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/) for an easy example.


You can also do it with the help of wordpress plugins.